# How do you assign two types of data to one variable?

Tags: c++, arrays, variables

I just started to learn C++ a couple weeks ago and I am trying to make a Blackjack game now. 
What I attempted to do was create an array that contained variables of all the cards such as: h1, hj, c4, ck; These stand for hearts 1, hearts jack, clubs 4, and clubs king.

I would like these variables to contain both a string (The name of the card) and an integer (the value of the number for adding).

Is there a way to have a variable contain two values?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you need an Object.

Comment: You should finish learning the basics of C++ before starting any kind of project

Comment: Note that if this is for a school project, which I suspect it is, make sure you thoroughly understand the implementation you choose. Structs or classes are likely what your teachers would be expecting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply speaking there's two solutions:

1) Use a tuple

```
std::tuple<std::string,int> Hearts1=std::make_tuple("h1", 12);
std::tuple<std::string,int> Clubs1=std::make_tuple("c1", 13)
```

See more: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple

2) Use Objects

```
class Hearts
{
  std::string name;
  int value;
};

class Clubs
{
  std::string name;
  int value
};

int main()
{
  Clubs CO; CO.name="abc"; CO.value=12;
  Hearts HO; HO.name="dce"; HO.value=13;
}
```

I suggest learning the basics of C++ programming prior to undertaking such a project. I strongly recommend "The C++ Programming Language"(B.Stroustrup) to get started with.

Comment: Cool thanks, this looks like it will work. I will look into that.

Comment: Rather than creating a separate class for each suit, consider writing `class card` and including suit as a property.

Answer (score 9):

You can create a struct for the variable that you need.

```
struct card
{
      string name;
      int value;
};
```

And then use this as follows:

```
card.name = "hearts";
card.value = 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also use two arrays with the same indexing. As long as you make sure they are created and updated simultaneously so that elements with the same index refer to the same card.